# The meaning of "would have" + the past participal of a verb in context

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

I have come across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/B5lzt42Tb20). It is 2 minutes and 28 seconds. Here is the context:

> Language is complex, and difficult to learn. So complex, that one relatively popular theory, which comes from famous linguist Noam Chompsky, is prewired into the human brain, and language **would** **have** suddenly **appeared** in the brain perhaps via a mutation in one individual withing the past 100,000 years.

I am totally confused about what that could mean and why it was used. It definitely doesn't look like an implied third conditional. What is the grammar of that?

Comment: which comes from **the** famous linguist Noam Chompsky. Please note: spoken language is not written language. It is common in science to use **would [have + verb]** to mean **allegedly appeared**.

Comment: @Lambie It’s perfectly OK to leave out the article in “famous linguist Chompsky” - it works either way in that context.

Comment: Off-topic nitpick but it's [Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky). But see also [Nim Chim**p**sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim_Chimpsky) :)